# High Lock Count in Windbg !heap -s, what's next I can do to detect unmanaged memory leak?

Tags: c#, windbg, unmanaged-memory

One of our PRD small win-service suddenly skyrocketed to 80+ GB memory for a few hours and then came down and stabilized at 6+ GB memory, it is usually use only under 200 MB. I have grab a memory dump at the time of 6+ GB, and restarted the server, everything go back to normal. I am investigating why it it skyrocketed to that high and why it's stabled at 6+ GB.

**I have found that it is an unmanaged memory leak issue, because the CLR heap is small:**

```
0:000> !eeheap -gc
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x000000910083ff20
generation 1 starts at 0x00000091007caba0
generation 2 starts at 0x0000009100001000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
         segment             begin         allocated              size
0000009100000000  0000009100001000  00000091029691f0  0x29681f0(43418096)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000009110001000
         segment             begin         allocated              size
0000009110000000  0000009110001000  000000911013dcb8  0x13ccb8(1297592)
Total Size:              Size: 0x2aa4ea8 (44715688) bytes.
------------------------------
***GC Heap Size:            Size: 0x2aa4ea8 (44715688) bytes.***
```

**But the Heap Summary is high, More suspiciously, the lock count is high**:

```
0:000> !heap -s


************************************************************************************************************************
                                              NT HEAP STATS BELOW
************************************************************************************************************************
LFH Key                   : 0x45d65d36d8f8b642
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
          Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                            (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**000000917aa90000 00000002 6718396 6682116 6718196  71860  5580   419    2     93   LFH**
000000917a850000 00008000      64      4     64      2     1     1    0      0      
000000917acd0000 00001002    1280     88   1080     15     7     2    0      0   LFH
000000917ac90000 00001002    1280    108   1080     24     8     2    0      0   LFH
000000917b160000 00001002    1280    124   1080      7    10     2    0      0   LFH
000000917b310000 00041002      60      8     60      5     1     1    0      0      
000000917bd40000 00041002     260     36     60      4     3     1    0      0   LFH
0000009118080000 00001002    1084   1024   1084   1021     2     1    0      0      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

0:000> !heap -stat -h 000000917aa90000
 heap @ 000000917aa90000
group-by: TOTSIZE max-display: 20
    size     #blocks     total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
    2d0b0 373e - 9b845aa0  (39.37)
    10d1 41962 - 44eed902  (17.45)
    ddc8 373e - 2fdbae70  (12.12)
    7ab8 373e - 1a7b4090  (6.70)
    7168 373e - 1878cf30  (6.20)
    29d1 6e6b - 1209485b  (4.57)
    35d1 372d - b995cbd  (2.94)
    31d1 372d - abca8bd  (2.72)
    12d1 6e5a - 81c6b7a  (2.05)
    21d1 3746 - 74d2626  (1.85)
    fd1 6e6c - 6d27a2c  (1.73)
    1cd1 372d - 635f7bd  (1.57)
    40 22b52 - 8ad480  (0.14)
    100 6ef7 - 6ef700  (0.11)
    200 374f - 6e9e00  (0.11)
    c3500 5 - 3d0900  (0.06)
    80 6edb - 376d80  (0.05)
    d8 374e - 2ea9d0  (0.05)
    249f18 1 - 249f18  (0.04)
    90 3792 - 1f4220  (0.03)
```

Then I did `!heap -flt s 2d0b0`

I can't do `!heap -p -a` to see the stack because I don't have gflags enabled in PRD.

Instead, I am trying to do a `dc 00000092b7088bb0 L200` to guess base on the string value. Nothing meaningful in the first chuck `(2d0b0 373e - 9b845aa0  (39.37)` But in the second chuck `( 10d1 41962 - 44eed902  (17.45))`, I found something like

```
00000092`b70b0250  00000000 00000000 44440000 4e4f4d2d  ..........DD-MON
00000092`b70b0260  0052522d 00000000 00000000 00000000  -RR.............
00000092`b70b0270  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
00000092`b70b0280  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
00000092`b70b0290  00000000 48480000 2e494d2e 46585353  ......HH.MI.SSXF
00000092`b70b02a0  4d412046 00000000 00000000 00000000  F AM............
00000092`b70b02b0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
00000092`b70b02c0  00000000 44440000 4e4f4d2d 2052522d  ......DD-MON-RR 
00000092`b70b02d0  4d2e4848 53532e49 20464658 00004d41  HH.MI.SSXFF AM..
00000092`b70b02e0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
00000092`b70b02f0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
00000092`b70b0300  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
00000092`b70b0310  00000000 48480000 2e494d2e 46585353  ......HH.MI.SSXF
00000092`b70b0320  4d412046 525a5420 00000000 00000000  F AM TZR........
00000092`b70b0330  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
00000092`b70b0340  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
00000092`b70b0350  00000000 00000000 44440000 4e4f4d2d  ..........DD-MON
00000092`b70b0360  2052522d 4d2e4848 53532e49 20464658  -RR HH.MI.SSXFF 
00000092`b70b0370  54204d41 0000525a 00000000 00000000  AM TZR..........
```

It looks like Oracle Database Query Date Time Format string. And We do use Oracle, and I am hard to believe that we are leaking oracle connections, because this small service have run for years and this is the first time this happened.
That's how far I can go now.

Sorry for the long question and thanks for spend time reading

**To summarize my question:**

1. what is the Lock Count Column mean in !heap -s , that looks like an
   indicator of an issue where I can keep digging, please point me a
   direction or blog I can read.
2. Are those Raw data string ring another bell on you instead of Oracle? Have you ever have similar issue?
3. We do use a lot .net remoting. I know it's old and I never deep dived into it. Does it could be a factor of this issue?
4. I can't do anything in PRD, and I can't reproduce this issue in DEV/TEST, is there any other direction I can take?

Comment: "Lock cont." is not "lock count". It is "lock contention." It's the number of times two threads tried to use the heap at the same time. 93 is not unreasonable for a long-running process with a lot of threads.

Comment: Wow, never thought that “cont” could mean something else  other than count. If that is not out of ordinary   Am I reaching a dead end already?

Comment: I've never seen `count` abbreviated `cont`. Since you have the heap, you can look around to see what's in it, see if the memory was simply leaked.

Comment: @RaymondChen How do I "see what's in it" other than 'dc 00000092b7088bb0 L200' which doesn't give me too much meaningful information? And what do you mean by "see if the memory was simply leaked" ? I know it is leaked because the memory is out of ordinary high and the Managed Heap size is small.

Comment: Yeah, dumping the heap blocks was what I had in mind. As for "simply leaked": Look for references to the unexpected heap blocks. Then look for references to those references. Keep going until you find a heap block that has no references to it. That is the block that was leaked.

Comment: @RaymondChen do you have any examples or blogs I can read and teach me how to do what you said? after I dump the heap blocks , How I can get meaningful information from raw memory data ?

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.debugthings.com/2015/01/09/debugging-heap-leaks/

Comment: @RaymondChen this solution require a "Step 1 - Enable GFlags" which I already mentioned that I can not do in PRD environment. Is there any other way that doesn't require Enable Gflags ?

Comment: You can use `!heap -p -a` or `!heap -srch` to look for a specific value in the heap. That's the "chasing references backwards" I was referring to.

Comment: If it went up to 80 GB and then back down to 6 GB it's not a leak. A leak just grows, but does not shrink.

Comment: 44 MB of GC memory? That's almost less than a Hello World application takes. Why is this application using .NET at all?

Comment: There are 14000 chunks of that data and you had a look at 2 of them. Use `.writemem` to write all of them to disk, then use some external analysis tools to check the contents. If nothing else helps, convert your crash dump into a picture like Dmitri Vostokov does. Seems other people have done this as well: https://github.com/habi/TOMCAT/blob/master/snippets/DMP2png.py

Comment: @ThomasWeller that's a very interesting idea, I probably will try it just for fun.